# A simple multiplication code embedded in html with pyscript

Tags: python, html, pyscript

I want to create a html web page that runs a python code via pyscript to multiply two given integers as follows:

- The integers "a" and "b" are given by an html form
- The output is printed as a*b in the "Output" area of the html page

Any suggestion would be preciated.

Here is what I did:

`

Multiply

```
<form onsubmit="return false">
    <label for="a">First number</label><br>
    <input type="integer" id="a" name="name" value=""><br>

    <label for="b">Second number</label><br>
    <input type="integer" id="b" name="name" value=""><br>

    <input pys-onClick="sub" type="submit" id="btn-form" value="submit">


</form> 

<p>Output:</p>
<p id = 'output'></p>
<py-script>

    def sub(*args,**kwargs):
        a = {Element('a').value}
        b = {Element('b').value}
        result_place = Element('output')
        result_place.write( a * b )

</py-script>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues.

When you load the code given in the question you will get a warning message:

> The attribute 'pys-onClick' and 'pys-onKeyDown' are deprecated. Please *(sic)* 'py-click="myFunction()"' or 'py-keydown="myFunction()"' instead.

So, the first modification is:

```html
<input py-click="sub()" type="submit" id="btn-form" value="submit">
```

Then, when you run the code after the first modification, you will get a new error:

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'set' and 'set'`

This is because you put `{}` around `Element('a').value` (and same for `b`) which turns that value into a set with one element, for example `{3}` if the first input field has the value 3.

So the second modification is:

```py
a = Element('a').value
b = Element('b').value
```

Running this code gives a new error:

`TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'`

This means that `input type="integer"` is not used by PyScript. So you will need to do the conversion yourself:

```py
result_place.write( int(a) * int(b) )
```

Then you will get the correct result:

[image]

Full MCVE:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<form onsubmit="return false">
    <label for="a">First number</label><br>
    <input type="integer" id="a" name="name" value=""><br>

    <label for="b">Second number</label><br>
    <input type="integer" id="b" name="name" value=""><br>

    <input py-click="sub()" type="submit" id="btn-form" value="submit">


</form> 

<p>Output:</p>
<p id = 'output'></p>
<py-script>

    def sub(*args,**kwargs):
        a = Element('a').value
        b = Element('b').value
        result_place = Element('output')
        result_place.write( int(a) * int(b) )

</py-script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that it would be better to check the input beforehand to see if the values are indeed integers (or other numeric types), now you can enter any value in the input and this will result in an error if the value is not an int.